# Simple dotnetcore app not running in VS Code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I tried to follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc

I did:

```
mkdir todoapi
cd todoapi
dotnet new webapi
```

When I opened Startup.cs in VS Code, I didn't get any warn message asking me the following:

```
Select Yes to the Warn message "Required assets to build and debug are missing from 'TodoApi'. Add them?"
Select Restore to the Info message "There are unresolved dependencies".
```

What is wrong with my local setup?

I just want to run this program from withi VS code.

If I run in debug mode I get this error:

```
The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1.
```

In the powershell terminal the command 'dotnet' doesn't work either. Should it?

**Update**

I re-started VS COde and now it picks up the command in terminal:
dotnet

Now when I run I get this:

> launch: launch.json must be configured. Change 'program' to the path
>   to the executable file that you would like to debug.

My launch.json has:

```
"configurations": [

        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Since you mention PowerShell, I guess you're on Windows. If you're saying `dotnet --version` doesn't work on PowerShell, maybe you need to reinstall .net core cli. For me, `dotnet --version` works fine when I enter it in PowerShell or Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dotnet restore      //restore dependencies
dotnet build        //build project
dotnet run          //run project
```

Comment: That works but not in VS Code.  I want to have it work using the vs code editor, not the command line.

Comment: You can do this with VS Code terminal by pressing ctrl+~ and running the above commands it will open the chrome debugger from VS Code.